# Is the flow of data inside the data flow tasks synchronous?

Tags: ssis

In Data flow task suppose I have source, couple of transforms and destination.

Say there are 1 million records to be read by source. Say it has reached row number 10000. Will the read rows (10000) get passed to the next transform or will the subsequent tasks wait for the previous task to completely process the rows? So only run transform when all 1 million have been read.

Answer (score 2):

It depends!

Quick definitions:

- Synchronous: One row in, one row out. Input lineage id is the same as output lineage id
- Asynchronous: N row(s) in, M row(s) out.
- Async, Fully blocking: All data must arrive before new data can leave
- Async, Partially blocking: Enough data must arrive before new data can leave

### All synchronous

```
OLE DB Source -> Derived Column -> OLE DB Destination
```

All synchronous components. 1M source rows, 10k rows flow from source, to column to destination. Lather-rinse-repeat

### Asynchronous, fully blocking

```
OLE DB Source -> 
                 Aggregate -> OLE DB Destination
```

Aggregate is an asynchronous, fully-blocking, component. 1M source rows, 10k rows flow from source to Aggregate (let's assume we're getting the Maximum sales grouped by sales id). It computes the maximum amount for the 10k it has, but it can't release them downstream because the 10k+1 row might have a larger value so it holds and stores the values until it has received an end of buffer signal from the source.

Only then, can the Aggregate component release the results to the downstream consumers of data.

I show the Aggregate not being "in line" with the source because at this point in a data flow, there is a rift between the data before and the data after. If it had been Source -> Derived column -> Aggregate, the Derived component is going to work on the same memory address (yay pointers) as the Source. Asynchronous components do an in memory copy of the data into a separate memory space. So, instead of being able to allocate 1GB to your data flow, it has to spend .5GB to the first half and .5 to the last half.

If you rename a column "upstream" from an asynchronous component, you can tell where the "break" in data lineage is because that column won't be available to the final destination until you modify all the async components between the source to the destination.

### Asynchronous, partially blocking

```
OLE Source DB 1 -->
                    Merge Join -> OLE DB Destination
OLE Source DB 2 -->
```

Merge join is an asynchronous, partially blocking component. You can usually tell the partially blocking components as they have a requirement of Sorted input. For an aggregate, we have to have **all** the data before we can say *this* is the maximum value.  With a merge join, since we know that both streams are sorted on key, we can release once the match key is out of matches. Assume I have the merge in an INNER JOIN configuration. If I have the rows with value of `A,B,C` from db1 feed and `A,C` from db2. While `A` matches `A`, we'll release rows to the destination. We exhaust As and go to the next. Source 1 provides `B`, Source 2 provides `C`. They don't match so `B` is discarded and the next Source 1 is retrieved. `C` matches so it continues on.

### It Depends(again)

```
OLE DB Source -> Script Component -> OLE DB Destination
OLE DB Source -> 
                 Script Component -> OLE DB Destination
```

A script component operates the way you define it. The default is synchronous but you can make it async.

Jorg has a good table flagging the components into the various buckets: https://jorgklein.com/2008/02/28/ssis-non-blocking-semi-blocking-and-fully-blocking-components/comment-page-2/

### The comment asks "What about a lookup transform?"

As the referenced article shows, Lookup is in Synchronous column. However, if one if looking for performance bottlenecks (async components are usually the first place I look), we often point out that the default lookup will cache all data in the table in the PreExecute phase. If your reference table has 10, 100, 1000000 rows, who cares. However long it takes to run `SELECT * FROM MyTable` and stream that from the database source to the machine SSIS is running on is the performance penalty you pay.

However, if you work at a mutual fund company and have a trade table that records prices for all of your stocks for all time, maybe *don't* try and pull that data back for a lookup transform, hypothetically speaking of course. Maybe you only needed to get the most recent settlement price so don't be lazy and pull more data than you'll ever need and/or crash the machine.

Comment: What about a lookup transform please?

Comment: @variable it depends on the caching option you're choosing for the lookup transformation. https://simplebiinsights.com/ssis-synchronous-and-asynchronous-transformations/

Comment: I disagree @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh with your conclusion. A lookup task is always going to be synchronous. One row in, one row out (whether it be Match, No Match or Error path). A new column added/removed from the data flow before the lookup will propagate through the data flow with no adjustment required on the lookup. The Cache option (Full, Partial, None) has no bearing on synchronicity. Cache affects the match rules (.NET vs database default), the mutability of the matched data and performance but ultimately, it remains a synchronous data flow component-as your linked article indicates.